# How to load view before add text to entry in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with OnAppearing function. I want to load the page first before adding the a text inside my entry. What is happening right now is that it is happening early meaning the text was inserted before the page has been loaded. Is there a way to solve this?

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    entEncodedBy.Text = "Admin";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any overloads of `await Task.Delay();` to wait a long as you want and then change the text.

Or

You can use `Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan, Func<Boolean>);`

Answer (score 0):

I not sure, but you can try add only await base.OnAppearing();
or you can just await Task.Run(()=>base.OnAppearing()); if this first method dont work.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you

Comment: Then maybe put Task in place where you initialize page.

Comment: show me how you going through to this page, or it is start page? And show me your constructor in this page.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to use `MessagingCenter`, you can refer to the following code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "Hi", async (sender) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000); // 2000ms == 2s
            entEncodedBy.Text = "Admin";
        });
    }

    protected override  void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "Hi");
    }
}
```

For more details, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center